# I am trying to keep my ListViewItems from being highlighted with a dotted border whenever I click on the item. Code is in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, material-design, listviewitem

I'm having a hard time getting this listview to function in the specific way I need. Currently, everything works correctly except for how the items are highlighted with a dotted border after being clicked. I believe it has something to to with IsSelected, but I'm not sure how to change that without messing up what I have.

```
<ListView x:Name="MainMenu" Foreground="#FF5C99D6" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style x:Name="TestStyleName" TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
            <EventSetter x:Name="TestEventName" Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>


    <!--REGION MAIN MENU-->
    <ListViewItem x:Name="MainHome" Height="60">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Home" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="10"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem x:Name="MainSearch" Height="60">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Magnify" Height="25" Width="25" Margin="10"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Search" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="20 10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```

I also tried putting this between the listview heading and the IemContainerStyle but that throws off my previous functionality. With this, it no longer throws the mouseclick event which is very important for my code.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Border Focusable="False" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" x:Name="border">
            <ContentControl SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
        <EventSetter x:Name="TestEventName" Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="true" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" />
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style x:Name="TestStyleName" TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
            <EventSetter x:Name="TestEventName" Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    ....Items...

</ListView>
```